# NoReverseMatch at /sitemap-main.xml

Tags: django

I am trying to set up a sitemap for the blog portion and main static portion of my website. I have been digging through the docs but nothing I have done is fixing this. I am thinking I am implementing the namespace incorrectly in sitemap_main.py but this is how it looks in the docs. The blog portion is working fine and I am getting the sitemap index page that gives the links to both sitemaps. But the sitemap for the static portion of the website isn't working. I get a NoReverseMatch at /sitemap-main.xml.

```
NoReverseMatch at /sitemap-main.xml
Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap-main.xml
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not    found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

website/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap

from .sitemap_main import StaticViewSitemap
from . import views

sitemaps = {
    'static': StaticViewSitemap,
}

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='home'),
    url(r'index$', views.index, name='home'),
    url(r'^gallery$', views.gallery, name='gallery'),
    url(r'^contact$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^about$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^about/testimonial$', views.testimonial, name='about'),
    url(r'^about/faq$', views.faq, name='about'),
    url(r'^services$', views.services, name='services'),
    url(r'^services/design$', views.design, name='design'),
    url(r'^services/lawn-garden$', views.lawn, name='lawn'),
    url(r'^services/irrigation$', views.irrigation, name='irrigation'),
    url(r'^services/spring$', views.spring, name='spring'),
    url(r'^services/hardscape$', views.hardscape, name='hardscape'),
    url(r'^sitemap-main\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
        name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap')

]
```

sitemap_main.py

```
from django.contrib import sitemaps
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class StaticViewSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5
    changefreq = 'daily'

    def items(self):
        return ['home', 'gallery', 'contact', 
                'services', 'design', 'lawn', 
                'irrigation', 'spring', 
                'hardscape']

    def location(self, item):
        return reverse(item)
```

Comment: How can I ensure that it is pulling from my `website.urls` file? There are three urls.py files on other  apps in the project.

Answer (score 2):

Got it! I did not use the app name for the namespace. Fixed with -

```
from django.contrib import sitemaps
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class StaticViewSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5
    changefreq = 'daily'

    def items(self):
        return ['website:home', 'website:gallery', 'website:contact', 
                'website:services', 'website:design', 'website:lawn', 
                'website:irrigation', 'website:spring', 
                'website:hardscape']

    def location(self, item):
        return reverse(item)
```